# Comparing two percentages

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, percentage

How would I go about comparing two percentage figures from two different sample sizes? For example:

- Sample 1 - 10% (220,510 out of 2,205,100) of respondents answered "yes",
- Sample 2 - 31% (12 out of 38) respondents answered "yes".

I want to compare these two percentages to determine if there is any significant difference. The larger sample is market data and I'm trying to compare sample 2 to the market data(sample 1). I don't have the means or SD so not sure how to go about comparing these two samples?

Comment: You will find a very detailed response in http://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/how-to-compare-two-population-proportions/    although without any exact calculations it is clear that the difference is significant,

Comment: I would look into a $\chi^2$ goodness of fit test  http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook//eda/section3/eda35f.htm

Comment: (I deleted some very misleading comments.)  Note that you have enough information to find *all* relevant means, SDs, SEs, and any moments you choose.  Thus you could compare the two samples very simply by quoting their means and standard errors or you could conduct a formal hypothesis test to compare their means.  Have you reviewed our posts on [tests of proportions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+test+of+proportion)